# How to convert a string containing a half precision floating point binary value to a signed short number in c++

Tags: c++, binary, type-conversion

I am currently trying to create a converter that takes in a decimal number and converts it to the half precision floating point binary value. The input is parsed from the user in decimal form into three strings: the sign, the whole number, and the fraction value. I have gotten the converter to work just fine, but now I am stuck trying to figure out how to handle the issue of overflow.

To illustrate, an example input could be `25.2` (which would make the whole number string `25` and the fraction `2`) and the fraction value of `2` when converted to binary is repeating `00110011...`. When it is input into the 16-bit signed binary number, there is an overflow bit that is set, so I need to round up by adding 1.

I figured that converting my final binary value to a `signed short` number in binary and adding 1 to it would be the simplest way of handling the overflow, however, I cannot seem to find any information on how to convert a string that contains a 16-bit signed binary number, for instance `"0100111001001100"` (`25.2` without overflow) to a `signed short` number so that I can add the overflow bit to it, convert it back to a string, and then output it.

Any suggestions on how to do this, or even other ways of solving this issue?

Comment: You can do many interesting things if you play with the `base` parameter in `std::stoi`. Sure, you get an `int` back rather than an `int16_t`, but that's relatively easy to handle with a bit of masking.

Comment: @user4581301 After having looked into the `base` parameter in `std::stoi` as you suggested, and I was actually able to convert the binary number to a decimal number that I could add to and convert back to binary number with a for loop and thus it solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: I started to type an answer, but I suspect to get it right, you'd need to explain this problem a bit more. Can you share your code and point to the issue you are stuck on. At first I thought you were trying to detect if a value like `.2` is an imprecise floating point value (not a power of 2) and would need remainder applied to it. Then I looked at it closer and thought you were asking how to "add 1" to a binary string.

Comment: @selbie Basically I was able to figure out how to use `std::stoi` to solve my problem but before I figured this out thanks to @user4581301 I was trying to convert numbers like `0.2` into their binary number equivalent using half precision 16-bit floating point. I already implemented a way to detect if the overflow bit was set or not, all I needed to implement was how to round the number up by adding 1 to it. I wanted to find a way to convert my string that held my output binary number to a `signed short` so I could just add 1 to it and then turn it back into a string and output it.